# How do I find the most square solution to units filling an area?

Tags: math, geometry, formula, algebra

I am in need of a formula which will allow me to calculate the most-square rectangle, made up a certain number of smaller rectangles?

I have the width and length of the smaller rectangles, I just don't have the width and length of the space that would be needed to fit them into it.

For example:
If I know I need to fit 16 units which are 4' by 1', then the correct answer would be 2 units by 8 units, because that would lead to an 8' by 8' square.

Thanks

Edited for clarity

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the smaller rectangles fit into a square? I assume not, but please clarify.

Comment: Are all the small rectangles of the sime size?

Comment: No, that is not guaranteed. I'd want to look for the closest to a square I could find.

Comment: Yes, all smaller rectangles are the same size.

Comment: Is the orientation of the small rectanges defined? I.e. width stays width, cannot be turned by 90 degrees.

Comment: The orientation is not defined, but they will all share whatever orientation is decided upon. I plan to run the equation twice, once for each orientation, then test for efficiency.

Comment: What do you mean by "most square"? Shortest circumference for defined area?

Comment: What do you mean by "2x8"? Two rows and 8 columns of units? That would be 16 units, not 8 as postulated.

Comment: Or length of 2 and width of 8? That would only be four units, not 8.

Comment: Edited for clarity. What I mean by "most square" is just as close as I can get to a square using the blocks I have. The least difference between the height and the width in length.

Comment: Actually I see my math is a bit off, editing again.. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies somewhat. But I still am confused by your example. 2 units by 8 units means using 16 units. But I understand that there are only 8 units in the example.

Comment: I recommend adding another example, which does not result in a perfect square.

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out a non-perfect square, is the problem. I can tell you a possible answer but don't know for sure it is the best one. To be clear, I don't mind if the square could possibly fit more units than what is called for. So if I was solving for 8 units of 3' by 3', then it would be ok to say 9' by 9', even though that leave a one-unit gap.

Comment: What would you want as a result for 11 units of 1x3? You get a pretty nice square with 6 and 5 units in two columns. It is 6x6 square, just one "missing" unit in the corner. Or does it have to be a perfect rectangle, in which case you will at least get total non-squares for all prime numbers of units.

Comment: I edited my comment just before yours and I think I addressed this.

Comment: True, yes answered.

Comment: I appreciate your attention on this, you're getting an up-vote on every comment.

Comment: Just determine the total area of all smalls. Take the square root.  Divide by shorter dimension.  Round up or down. Try the four combinations. Choose the nicest.

Comment: I am shooting for an upvote of an answer. Do not have one yet...

Comment: E.g. 8 units of 3x3. Total area 8*9==72. Square root 8.48. Divided by 3= 2.82. Round (up): 3. Divide 8 by that 3: 2,66. Round up:3. Result 3 units by 3 units. 3*3*3*3 area of too large square/rectanlge is 81. Too much by 9, ie. a gap of one unit.

Comment: Seems like it would work to me. If you submit it as an answer, I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the square root of the known (minimum) total area of all the units as the perfect length of a square if that is possible. Divide it by the larger dimension.

If not a perfect square you need to find a compromise. This depends a bit on context and opinion, maybe I do not see your side requirements.

But I propose for example:

8 units of 3x3. Total area 8*9==72.
Square root 8.48. Divided by 3= 2.82. Round (up): 3.
Divide 8 by that 3: 2,66. Round up:3. Result 3 units by 3 units.
3*3*3*3 area of too large square/rectanlge is 81.
Too much by 9, i.e. a gap of one unit.

XXX XXX XXX
XXX XXX XXX
XXX XXX XXX

XXX XXX XXX
XXX XXX XXX
XXX XXX XXX

XXX XXX
XXX XXX
XXX XXX